# Display a Texturethat is loaded in class1 using its object in class2 libgdx

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

Have tried to load a texture in one class named load which contains some other loading and displaying of assets

later in another class tried to use the same Texture **solvebox** by creating a object of the class load

```
  public class load{

    @Override
    public void show() {

        try {
            XmlReader reader = new XmlReader();
            Element element = reader.parse(Gdx.files.internal(
                    "data/loadassets.xml").read());.....

            Element help = element.getChildByName("help");...
            solvebox = new Texture(
                    Gdx.files.internal("data/" + help.get("box")));
    }

    ...
    }
```

now in another class created a obj of this and tried to draw it...

```
class correct{
....
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    load obj=new load();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(obj.solvebox, ((w / 2) - (w / 15f)), (h / 3));
    batch.end();
...
    }
```

but its displaying an `NullPointerException` at this location where i wish to draw it the second time using object of the class load

```
> 09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
> 26856
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523): java.lang.NullPointerException
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.renderMesh(SpriteBatch.java:1042)
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.end(SpriteBatch.java:267)
>     **
>     
>     > 09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):    at
>     > com.invntn.screens.CorrectScreen.render(CorrectScreen.java:86)
>     
>     **
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.invntn.trycolor.TryColor.render(TryColor.java:42)
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the second code snippet, it looks like you haven't called obj.show() before using obj.solvebox. So solvebox hasn't been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

check at this line:

```
>     09-06 16:56:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(30523):  at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.renderMesh(SpriteBatch.java:1042)
```

as this is the point where you are getting `NullPointerException`. check every object on this for `null` value and check what causing it to be `null`